# How to insert "k" number of points between two points in C++?

Tags: c++, geometry

I have two curves with an equal number of data points. I want to connect the corresponding points on the curves with "k" equally spaced points to form a straight line.

[How it should look](https://github.com/aakarnik/Images/blob/master/Curves.png)

I have tried to use the following formula to calculate both x's and y's lying on the path between the points:

```
    for(int j = 1; j<=num_k; j++) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= (num_points-1); i++) {
            x[i][j] = x[i][1] * (1. - j/num_k) +  x[i][num_points] * j/num_k;
            y[i][j] = y[i][1] * (1. - j/num_k) +  y[i][num_points] * j/num_k;
        }
    }
```

The data points of the curve are stored in the first and last columns of 2D arrays `x` and `z`.
`num_k` is the number of intervals I want. `num_points` is the number of points on both the curves.

But this is not giving me the result that I need - this gives me the points, but they are not between the two input points as given. Am I using the right technique or is there something else I should be using? Also, are there any special cases?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] -- in this case, you need the type of all variables used (even fake types!  All that matters is that the types you use display a similar problem), and a tiny test harness that displays the problem.  Second, please describe what goes wrong -- "they are not between" -- are they on the moon?  On top of one of the points?  WHY THE MYSTERY?  I mean, I could say "well, you have some integer math there if some of your types are integers, and division in integers probably isn't what you want", but that would be a guess with only a ~80% chance of being right.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I understand your concern. Thanks for the guidelines and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1. - j/num_k)` will almost always evaluate to 1, because `j/num_k` is done using integer math, which will mean it will be zero except on the last iteration.

Use  `(1. - double(j)/num_k)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that was what the problem was!